# Android SQLite Couldn't Found Declared Column

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Okay, here's the situation: I've created a class extending Android's `SQLOpenHelper` class. I've also implemented the required methods, `onCreate` and `onUpgrade`, to initialize tables and to drop the current tables and then re-create new ones respectively.

The tables were successfully created but when I tried to call a method to insert a new record to the database LogCat gave me this instead:

```
06-17 21:31:19.907: I/SqliteDatabaseCpp(561): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = table calendarEvents has no column named colour, db=/data/data/stub.binusitdirectorate.calendar/databases/calendarSQLite
```

I've done some search regarding this problem. Most of the answers suggested to re-install the app and repeat the process. Done, but still no success.

Here's my SQLiteOpenHelper `onCreate` method:

```
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            String CREATE_EVENTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + EVENTS_TABLE + "("
                    + KEY_EVENTS_TYPE_ID + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY,"
                    + KEY_EVENTS_TYPE_NAME + " TEXT," + KEY_EVENTS_NAME + " TEXT,"
                    + KEY_EVENTS_COLOR + "TEXT," + KEY_EVENTS_START_DATE + "DATE,"
                    + KEY_EVENTS_END_DATE + "TEXT" + ")"
    
            db.execSQL(CREATE_EVENTS_TABLE);
        }
```

And here's my method for inserting new records:

```
    public void addEventsList(ArrayList<CalendarEventData> lstCalendarEvents) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        if (lstCalendarEvents != null && db != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < lstCalendarEvents.size(); i++) {
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

                values.put(KEY_EVENTS_TYPE_ID, lstCalendarEvents.get(i)
                        .getEventTypeId());
                values.put(KEY_EVENTS_TYPE_NAME, lstCalendarEvents.get(i)
                        .getEventTypeName());
                values.put(KEY_EVENTS_NAME, lstCalendarEvents.get(i)
                        .getEventName());
                values.put(KEY_EVENTS_COLOR, lstCalendarEvents.get(i)
                        .getColour());
                values.put(KEY_EVENTS_START_DATE, DateUtils
                        .getFormattedDateString(lstCalendarEvents.get(i)
                                .getStartDateTime(), dateFormat));
                values.put(KEY_EVENTS_END_DATE, DateUtils
                        .getFormattedDateString(lstCalendarEvents.get(i)
                                .getEndDateTime(), dateFormat));

                db.insert(EVENTS_TABLE, null, values);
             }

            db.close();
         }

    }
```

I'm fairly new to Android and was using [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/) as a guide.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: On a side note: `String KEY_EVENTS_COLOR` contains "colour". So it is not a typo :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part of your create statement might cause problems

```
KEY_EVENTS_COLOR + "TEXT," + KEY_EVENTS_START_DATE + "DATE,"
                + KEY_EVENTS_END_DATE + "TEXT" + ")"
```

You are missing a space before TEXT everywhere :)

Comment: Wow. Never would have thought that, but apparently SQLite uses dynamic typing and does not require a datatype. I was even more suprised that even if you do specify a datatype you can insert others as well (for example, you may insert a string into an int column). This behaviour is described [here](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity)

Comment: It worked! Thank a bunch mate!

Never would've thought that the culprit would be so small -- a mere space!